# Undefined reference error when accessing OpenSSL AES_encrypt function through NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, aes, undefined-reference

I am trying to write a wrapper for encryption/decryption file for Android using OpenSSL open source library. So I created a NDK Android project to compile library OpenSSL using NDK.

Here is project structure:

```
Android Project
    src
    jni
        openssl-1.0.1e     (folder contains openssl source code)
            crypto         (folder contains crypto source code)
                Android.mk (the Android makefile to define STATIC_LIBRARY)

            include
                openssl    (folder contains header files)

        wrapper            (folder contains wrapper source code, my implementation here)
            aes_wrapper.c  (my wrapper implementation)
            Android.mk     (the Android makefile to define SHARED_LIBRARY)

        Android.mk         (the Android makefile that calls all sub android makefiles)
        Application.mk     (the Application makefile, I use to define APP_ABI)
```

Here is content of Android.mk in folder jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH) \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/asn1 \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/aes \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/evp \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/include \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/include/openssl

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := all source files here

LOCAL_MODULE    := crypto

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Here is content of Android.mk in folder jni/wrapper

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH) \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/asn1 \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/aes \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/evp \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/include \
    $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/openssl-1.0.1e/include/openssl

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := aes_wrapper.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += crypto

LOCAL_MODULE    := aes_wrapper

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is content of Android.mk in folder jni

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

Here is content of Application.mk in folder jni

```
APP_ABI := all
```

When I call ndk-build I got some "undefined reference to" errors. I have been trying to fix a couple of days but unfortunately I was not successful. Could anyone help me? Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I got bunch of errors like this

```
/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/aes_wrapper/aes_wrapper.o: in function encrypt:jni/wrapper/aes_wrapper.c:21: error: undefined reference to 'AES_encrypt'
```

Comment: I would recommend you include the full error text in your question.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call ndk-build I got some "undefined reference to" errors. I have been trying to fix a couple of days but unfortunately I was not successful.

It sounds like `AES_encrypt` is not you only error. For `AES_encrypt`, here's where its located:

```
$ grep -R AES_encrypt *
crypto/aes/aes.h:void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
...
crypto/aes/aes_core.c:void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
...
```

I don't use the NDK build system, so I'm not sure if `aes_core.c` is actually being compiled from your example.

However, you do have `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += crypto`, and you can verify the function is present in the archive with the NDK's version of `nm` (I believe its `arm-linux-androideabi-nm`) as follows. You want to see an entry with a `T` (`T` is a definition in the Text section):

```
$ nm libcrypto.a | grep -i AES_encrypt
...
                 U AES_encrypt
0000000000000460 T AES_encrypt
0000000000000000 t _x86_64_AES_encrypt
00000000000001f0 t _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact
...
```

If you are still having trouble, OpenSSL offers direction for building the library from the command line outside of the NDK build system. See [FIPS Library and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android) (and skip the FIPS part). From [Build the FIPS Capable Library](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android#Build_the_FIPS_Capable_Library):

```
# From the 'root' directory
$ . ./setenv-android.sh
$ cd openssl-1.0.1e/

$ ./config shared no-ssl2 no-comp no-hw no-engine \
    --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/$ANDROID_API

$ make depend
$ make all
$ sudo -E make install \
    CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    RANLIB=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
```

In the recipe above, `ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN` is set by the `setenv-android.sh` script.

Also, you can usually find something prebuilt on Github. http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+android+site:github.com